# Update version of Maven within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Within Eclipse, If I click on Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations, I see my Maven version is 3.3.3.  How would dI update that to version 3.3.9, which is the most recent version?  If I can't do that, aside from downloading a newer version of Eclipse, is there any way to update the version of Maven that the project uses?  Thanks!

Comment: You could use an external Maven installation within Eclipse. Just add one and mark it instead of the embedded one.

Answer (score 6):

You can't update the Maven installation that is embedded inside Eclipse, but you can configure it to use an external Maven installation of your choice.

If you go to "Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations", you can click "Add..." and point to an external Maven installation. From there, you can select an installation of Maven 3.3.9, and select it as the default Maven to use for M2Eclipse.

Comment: Notice that an external version of Maven won't be used for dependency resoluton though